# Why do I have to click the movie for my character to respond?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My movie has 3 frames, first one is the welcome screen with the play button, and after I press it and jumped to frame2 I have to click the movie for my character/player to respond and move by arrows. Same happens if I go back to frame2 from my game-over screen placed on frame3.

I use `gotoAndPlay();` to navigate frames, naturally.

if it's something having to do with my code from frame2 i will post what it is required. I'd like to know why is that happening and how to fix it. THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking your character gives it focus.
Only* what has focus receives keyboard events.

If you register the listener for the keyboard event on your character object, you have to click it first, before it receives those events.

**However**, the KeyboardEvents bubble up the display list and eventually reach the top most container which is the stage. This gives you two options:

1. Handle the focus yourself by assigning the object that should have focus to the stage.focus property. This is basically doing what the clicking does in your current situation.http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#focus
2. register your listeners at the stage

Comment: For anybody that may find this useful: I used stage.focus = stage; so that you don't have to click.

Answer (score 0):

The user simply needs to click anywhere on the flash stage to add keyboard focus. Normally, a good way of achieving this is by using a start button, or something similar, for that first bit of mouse/keyboard focus.